# How to rename multiple files in BASH removing specifically an n number of character from back to front

Tags: bash, rename

I have this sort of files:

> foo_bar_hfh4.ext
>
> foobar_bar_2fr4.ext
>
> foobar_foobar_5ytu.ext
>
> foobarfoobar_foobar_rtnm.ext

etc.

and my question is how to remove the last 5 (or n) characters from each name, keeping the extension. The number of characters is always different in every file, so it can't be done by seeking from left to right.

The **_** character always appears twice and is the first character in the series of 5 that I need to remove. There is no other pattern in the characters to be removed.

I'm aware that the Thunar Bulk Rename can easily accomplish this in gui. But what about BASH?

Comment: `rename 's/.{5}(\.[^.]*)$/$1/' *`

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: I made a minor change to your code:
       rename 's/.{5}(\.[^.]*)$/$1/' *.ext
so that only the .ext files are affected (there are other files in the same directory; forgot to mention)

Answer (score 0):

The perl `rename` utility is made for this kind of problem:

```
rename 's/.{5}([.][^.]*)$/$1/' *
```

**Note:** This requires the perl version of `rename`. There is also a `rename` utility that is part of util-linux but it is *completely incompatible*.  Do not try to use it with the command above.

Comment: Are you refering to "libfile-rename-perl"? Because that one isn't installed in my system and yet your command worked well.

Comment: If the command above works, then it is the right one.  On debian-like systems, `rename` is included with the default perl package under the name `prename`.  A slightly different version is part of the [rename](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/rename) package.  `libfile-rename-perl` is a virtual package that installs `rename`.  There are, unfortunately, some linux distributions that have the other incompatible one installed by default.